# Mongoose Connection Pool

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I noticed in the Mongoose docs that there is support for a connection pool.

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html

Considering that node is single threaded why is there a connection pool? 
What's the lifecycle of connections in the pool?

Comment: Node isn't single threaded under the hood. The javascript runs in the same thread but many operations, especially IO operations, are done in background threads. Thus if you make multiple calls to the database those are done in background threads, simultaneously. The results are marshalled back to the main thread and processed one at a time by your javascript but the non-javascript parts of your code are processed in parallel essentially.

Answer (score 20):

Connection pools don't have anything to do with async vs sync -- it just works like so:

- You can specify an amount of open connections to maintain to your database (let's say 10).
- Each time your Node JS code makes a query, if possible, it'll use one of the already-open 10 connections to make this request -- this way you can avoid the overhead of opening a new database connection for each query.

Maintaining a connection pool is essentially maintaining an array of db connection objects, and picking unused ones for every query. It's not actually effecting threads or processes at all =)

Comment: Isn't async an important distinction here? If it was synchronous and single threaded. Then even though you had N connections in your pool you'd only ever use 1. So I'm assuming mongoose is taking advantage of  node's async nature. i.e. one command/query might be blocking while another is streaming data over a different connection?

Comment: sync vs async won't matter here, there's still going to be a heavy cost delay for opening and closing connections one-at-a-time (even if you're doing it async) -- what you'll notice is that your queries will become more and more slow over time, since you're spending memory on opening / closing connections.

Comment: that could be solved with 1 persistent connection that you reuse.. not necessarily a pool of connections.

Comment: With one persistent connection you can only process a single query at a time. If you're using async calls this won't work, as you'll still need to open new connections for each other connection when the single persistent one is busy :(

Comment: Hence the reason I said async was the thing I said I was missing when I was confused about why pools were helpful. :)

Comment: i need to do exactly that, do you know where can i find a example of it? Thank you @rdegges

Comment: In a scenario of multitenant app (multiples databases, i.e., multiple databases connections), where the connections are not open on app boot, instead it is created as needed, being scoped by request subdomain: I use the mongoose.createConnection().. my question is, should I close the connection after on the end of the request? If it is not needed to close, in the next request I have to call again mongoose.createConnection(), what will happen in this case? Will it use the connection opened before or it will create a new one?

Answer (score 2):

apparently node is a single threaded but internally when node makes a call to IO operation under the hood it has some threading mechanism through which it performs IO. Main thread doesn't perform this IO operation itself, if it was performing IO, system would be dead already.

https://codeburst.io/how-node-js-single-thread-mechanism-work-understanding-event-loop-in-nodejs-230f7440b0ea